# What's the meaning of this quote? "May he who loves not others love himself."

Tags: meaning, quotes

"May he who loves not others love himself." What's the meaning of this quote? I couldn't understand it.

Comment: Where did you find it? Could you link us to it or provide more context?

Comment: It's about Narcissus in Greek Mythology. "Narcissus went on his cruel way, a scorner of love. But at last one of those he wounded prayed a prayer and it was answered by the Gods: "May he who loves not others love himself." The great goddess Nemesis, which means righteous anger, undertook to bring this about. As Narcissus bent over a clear pool for a drink and saw there his own reflection, on the moment he fell in love with it. "Now I know," he cried, "What others have suffered from me, for I burn with love of my own self.

Comment: I took this context from the book of Edith Hamilton.

Comment: His sin was not loving others, spurning their love for him. His punishment was — if he would not love others, he at the very least would love himself. So he did. And died of it. And today we still name this fatal disease after him: *narcissism*.

Comment: In archaic English, the adverb 'not' could be used like part of a phrasal verb.  In modern English it only follows an auxiliary verb: "May he who *does not love* others love himself [at least]."